# I need to generate burst mode PWM signal to drive MOSFET. How can I do that in LTspice?

Tags: power-electronics

[image]
I need to generate this signal in LTspice. Is there any way to generate it?

Comment: Michel robert - Hi, Did you copy that image from somewhere? [This site rule](/help/referencing) requires that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). If that image is not your own work, please [edit] the question & add a suitable reference. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) TY (Please see the [tour] & [help].)

Answer (score 5):

You can use some voltage sources to create pulses and then combine them using formulas in behavioral voltage sources.

The voltages can be used like logic signals, set the pulse \$V_{on}\$ to 1 V and you can then multiply them to get an AND result. Using !(x) or inv(x)  will invert the signal giving `0 if x > .5, else 1`.

Here's an example giving \$V_{G1}\$ to \$V_{G4}\$ similar to your diagram.
[image: PWM signal using behavioral sources]

You could set up parameters for the pulse timing, and the output voltages can be scaled by using voltage dependent voltage sources (go to add component and select *e*, connect the two minus terminals to ground, the voltage you want to scale to the input +, right click the symbol and set *value* to what you want to multiply the voltage by.